# Find multiple pattern matches and replace each one in a text file

Tags: java

I want to find multiple string matches and replace in a text file and  replace unique for each pattern.

Example

> I have the following patterns to match and replace respectively

I want to find this patterns 1 ."cd", 2. "kj", 3."by"   and replace by this: 1."sdi" 2."ge" 3. "bi".

```
 BufferedReader cd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));

 String line;
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("cd",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
 Matcher matcher;
 while ((line = cd.readLine()) != null) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.find()) {
       line = matcher.replaceAll("sdi");
       System.out.println(line); cd.close();
```

This simple code works for single pattern match. Is there any other way possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just do something like this?

```
yourstring.replaceAll("cd", "sdi").replaceAll("kj", "ge").replaceAll("by", "bi");
```

This way, the compiler will take care of implementing and matching the patterns.

Comment: Could use `"(?i)cd"` for case-insensitive, `\\b` for word boundaries.